# How to find complex objects in an Object from a String (these have to be separeted with dots) - Angular -

Tags: javascript, typescript

I hope you are very well.

I am trying to find an complex object in an Object in Angular from a String (the content of this String is dynamic).

For example:

```
 let variable = {
      "name":"Rick",
      "family": {
        "son":"Andy"
      }
    };
```

When I try to read the **name** attribute, I can find it with the code:

```
console.log(variable["name"]);
```

When I try to read the **family** attribute, I can find it with the code:

```
console.log(variable["family"]);
```

However when I try to read the **son** attribute, I have tried to make with the code:

```
console.log(variable["family.son"]);
```

But I have gotten an ***undefined*** value, I found that I can use any of the followings codes:

```
console.log(variable["family"]["son"]);
console.log(variable["family"].son);
```

But it is not working for me, because I need to search the attribute from a String (the attributes are Dynamics), Does someone know how can I solve this.

The String contains the attribute path, for instance:  "family.son" or "family"

Regards.

Comment: And this string contains what? This has nothing to do with Angular or AngularJS BTW. It's a pure JavaScript or TypeScript question.

Comment: You're not using an array either. You're using an object

Comment: So split the string using `.` as the separator, and use a loop to get the properties one by one.

Comment: @nullptr.t there is not any wrong with use two String, however for my case I need to make it with once String, please help me reading the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
const dotPathAccessor = (src, path) => {
    const parts = path.split('.');
    return parts.reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], src);
}
const variable = {
    "name": "Rick",
    "family": {
        "son": "Andy"
    }
};

console.log(dotPathAccessor(variable, "family.son"));

// you can use a Proxy object to make it simpler
// with this prototype, you can now get a dot proxy for any object using `object.getDotProxy`
// and access it using dot paths
Object.prototype.getDotProxy = () => new Proxy(variable, {
    get(obj, prop) {
        return dotPathAccessor(obj, prop);
    }
});
const dotProxy = variable.getDotProxy();

console.log(dotProxy["family.son"]);
```